# Kinetic, change stage/container or open new stage/container/layer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm new in kinetic with canvas,

I cannot differ stage, container,layer yet and I want to make a game that have a map.

On that map you will see some countries. When i click on one country, it will open a new layer/container that have a room.

I don't know how to add click event on it.

For example, i will make click event on animal in [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/) and when I click on animal, it will open below [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-shape-tango-with-kineticjs/)

How to add click event on it?

Comment: Please try to make your question a little bit readable and place the codes you have tried to help others understand and see the problem. Description give a very faint image of the problem.

Comment: you will be able to do this with the X and Y of the click. There is no Element selection in canvas as they are only bitmap. Unfortunately it is not like the Element on DOM that you can choose with ID or Class.

Comment: That's incorrect, Manuel. Kinetic handles shape selection in canvas elements. Of course, I can barely understand the question, so perhaps your response is correct in a context I have missed. ;)